# Mongodb spatial data with date fields - best index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My mongodb has many lat/lon points (~14 billion right now). Till now I have only been generating these points, but now I am ready for reading. I now need to create an index. My main query will need to be able to find nearby points based on some lat/lon cooridnates sorted by time (newest first) and only will only show the first X results. I need the searches to be within 500m - 1000m (I am easy when it comes to accuracy, but it needs to be around this distance). A geohaystack index looks great for my use case:

> A geoHaystack index is a special index that is optimized to return results over small areas. geoHaystack indexes improve performance on queries that use flat geometry.

This sounds perfect for me as I seem to meet this criteria. Looking at the how to query this index I come up with this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoSearch/#dbcmd.geoSearch

I can see I can limit the query, but how would I sort by time? How to best index this time?

Since geohaystack does nto specify what is a "small" area and how many points can be in an area, is this index okay for my use case? As well, is there a better way (read-performance wise, willing to give up accuracy for speed) to find the nearest points sorted by time and limited?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need _spherical geometry_ ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux The reason I didn't choose it is for performance reasons as I have read that flat surfaces will give better peformance as spherical functions such as circle radius take more time to compute

Comment: You know better than me your requirements -- but in the general case, using flat geometry primitive is simply inexact when applied on longitude/latitude pairs -- and you will add an extra complexity to take care of area crossing the -180°/180° longitude line and at for area over the poles. Spherical geometry handle all of that for you. _If_ your main concern is about spherical geometry performances and how to improve them, maybe _that_ would be a very good question to ask here (BTW: have you conducted some benchmark to see how long it takes to find and match such a high number of docs?)